# Allowing users to connect with SSH without having sudo access?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Here's what I'm trying to do: set up a backup server on Google Compute Engine, where employees at my company can have their computers backup nightly via rdiffbackup. A cron job will run that runs rdiffbackup, which uses SSH to send files just like SCP.

With a "normal" server, I can create each employee a new user, and set permissions so they cannot read another employee's files.

It seems like using the "gcloud compute ssh" tool, or configuring regular ssh using "gcloud compute config-ssh", only allows you to allow users to connect who are added to the project and have connected their computer to their google account. My issue with this is that I don't see a way for a user to have read-write abilities on a server without also being a sudoer (anyone added to a project with "Can Edit" can get sudo as far as I know). Obviously if they have sudo, they can read others' files.

Can I give someone the ability to SSH remotely without having sudo? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend avoiding gcloud all together for this. gcloud's SSH tools are geared towards easily administering a constantly changing set of machines in your project. It is not made to cover all use cases that would also use SSH.

Instead, I recommend you setup your backup service as you would a normal server:

- assign a static address
- (optional) assign a dns name
- setup users on the box using adduser

Comment: Ahh, I thought I read that it wasn't possible to set up a server in that way on GCE, that you had to use their SSH tools to connect and you couldn't create an arbitrary user that could login via SSH. Just created a user, set up the authorized_keys, and it works. Thank you.

Comment: You need to use either gcloud or the cloud console to setup your initial login. After that, it is just a normal server. There is a daemon running on the server to fetch new keys/users from Google. You may wish to disable that.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of options

1) You can manage non-root users on your instances as you would on any normal Linux machine with by manually adding them with the standard commands like 'adduser' and not gsutil/UI/metadata update path.

2) Alternatively if you need to manage a large cluster of machines you can disable the entire ACL management provided by Google and run your own LDAP server for this. The file which is responsible for the account updates and needs to be disabled to run is this one 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/blob/master/google-daemon/etc/init/google-accounts-manager-service.conf

3) Finally you can lock down write access to the root users ie. disable writes propagating from metadata server by setting the immutable flag on the sudoers file 'chattr +i /etc/sudoers' Its not a graceful solution but effective. This way you lock in Root for the already added users and any new users will be added as non-root privileged, any new root level user needs to be added manually machine by machine though.