# GCP SSH keys gives sudo user access, how can we avoid it?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, ssh, ssh-keys

I have created 3 ssh key pairs for three users and they can ssh to a VM that is in on one of my projects on GCP. The problem is that all of these users have sudo access because when I execute the following it tells that they have all accesses:

```
sudo -l -U user

Matching Defaults entries for user on project:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User user may run the following commands on project:
    (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

How can I restrict their access to an ordinary user?

This is how I created my keys:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f {path}\{key-name} -C {user-name}
```

Then, I copied the public key and added to `ssh keys` in console.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012260/allowing-users-to-connect-with-ssh-without-having-sudo-access and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62594620/remove-user-from-google-sudoers-in-google-cloud-platform-linux-box

Comment: Add specific details on how you created the SSH keypairs, created the user accounts, and how you added the public keys to the VM.

Comment: You seem to be looking for the `sudo deluser username sudo` command, but just to be sure, add details to your post for a more specific answer.

Comment: @John Hanley: I added how I created my keys and how I added my public keys to the VM.

Comment: @Alex G: I added how I created my keys and how I added my public keys to the VM.

Comment: I think the Compute Engine startups scripts will set up the user when you install SSH public keys via the Google Cloud Console GUI. To confirm create a new user and install the SSH public key in their **.ssh/authorized_keys** file bypassing (not using) the GUI.

Comment: Please move your question to [su], [sf] or [devops.se] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @John Hanley: I added a new user by `sudo useradd user` and created a new public and private keys, then I added the public key to `.ssh/authorized_keys`. When I try to ssh using this new one user, I get `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: @Sepide - Review the OpenSSH server logs to know why. Make sure the file permissions are correct for the directory **.ssh** and the file **authorized_keys**.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use a `VM startup script` to find all users that you don't want to give sudo access and remove them from `google-sudoers` group.